# How to read partitioned data in Spark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, data-partitioning

A lot of examples suggest to read data like `spark.read("path/partition=value/*")` but how to defined a column from path?

For example, I want to read from `path/2019/12/31/*` and get columns `year`, `month`, `day` **which are derived from path** not from data itself. How to do that with pyspark?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery

Comment: How is works when there is no name in partition? Like `/M/` instead of `/gender=M/`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question: `how to define a column from path?`

Depends on the file format. Ie. on `parquet` this information is stored in file path.

If your dataframe is stored partition-wise as a parquet table with partition columns `year, month, day` then it will look like

```scala
/yourParquetLocation/year=2019/month=12/day=31
```

so this will work

```scala
spark.read.parquet("/yourParquetLocation/year=2019/month=12/day=31")
```